# Is it possible to make a Twilio app call to native original contact mobile number?

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

I am developing an app with Twilio APIs integration. Using this, I am able to make a call from App to App. What I need is call from App to mobile number?

First, kindly guide me is it possible to do such call? Like what Uber is doing, app to phone number call?

Second, if possible, kindly show me some coding directions for this?

Third, it's for iOS in Swift language.

In my case, only one person say "car-driver" have this app, and "car-driver" don't have any contact information for "customer" (customer don't have this app. Customer will register from web portal).

So, now the issue is : How a car-driver will make a call his/her customer's phone number?

Comment: _guide me is it possible to do such call?_ Use google first, come back once you stuck. _show me some coding directions for this_ Show us your code to help you!

Comment: I googled alot. Didn't find anything specific. 

If you know something, please guide.

Anticipating favorable reply soon !!!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [Masked Phone Numbers tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/python/flask) with examples in several popular server-side languages.

The example for connecting a call will look something like this:

```
@app.route('/exchange/voice', methods=["POST"])
def exchange_voice():
    form = ExchangeForm()

    outgoing_number = _gather_outgoing_phone_number(form.From.data, form.To.data)

    response = twilio.twiml.Response()
    response.addPlay("http://howtodocs.s3.amazonaws.com/howdy-tng.mp3")
    response.addDial(outgoing_number)
    return twiml(response)
```

We don't recommend you handle everything client-side as it reveals a potential vulnerability in your app. You can read more about that in this [Swift post for sending SMS from your app](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/how-to-send-an-sms-from-ios-in-swift.html). The example here shows you how to make and HTTP request to a Python server using Alamofire.

Between these two resources, I think you'll be well on your way!